# How to change Raspberry Pi's MAC address while connected over SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, mac-address

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B connected over SSH (Putty with Xming server), I wanted to change the MAC address but each time when I enter the command 'sudo ipconfig eth0 down', my SSH session will get disconnected and deleted. I've searched online for quite some time but I could not find any solution or explanation about this problem (some sites only mention to not to connect SSH while changing MAC address).

My question is that is it possible to change the MAC address of a Raspberry Pi while connected over SSH? If not, is there any workaround on it? Because I do not have a separate monitor, only a laptop, therefore can only access Raspberry Pi over SSH.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a MAC address and keep an existing connection. Changing the MAC address means the whole networking stack must be re-established.

> My question is that is it possible to change the MAC address of a Raspberry Pi while connected over SSH?

Make a script that completes the change, and re-establishes the network stack. Execute the script in such a way that it keeps running when the SSH connection is broken (e.g. with `screen` or `tmux`, or by detaching from the controlling terminal), so you can ssh in again after the network is up.

The more important question is: Why do you want to do this? Changing the MAC address in a system with network connections makes about as much sense as doing a 100m spring while someone pulls out your feet from under you.

If you want your RaspPi to have a particular MAC address, **configure** it so it uses this MAC address when it comes up.

Also, having different MAC addresses is usually not something you need.

Comment: I'm doing this because I'm trying to experiment with Raspberry Pi and try to come up with some basic program that could improve security/privacy while connected over the network or browsing the internet. Thank you for your detailed answer, I will have a good look through it and try to understand it further.

Comment: Changing the MAC address will make no different at all outside the local LAN segment, and it's **necessary** to know the correct MAC address inside the local LAN segment. The worst thing the MAC address can be used for is to identify the device while you are in a segment where other observers can see the MAC address (e.g. unencrypted WLAN). For everything else, it's not going to improve security if you tinker with it. In particular, "browsing the internet" is completely disconnected from the MAC address.